# How to make a prediction in the android with timeseries

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was train a model and make a label from the data.
the label here is 1 and 0, is mean 0 is for fog and 1 is for normal. the I got the data from the insole is double array as

> [133.0, 138.0, 133.0, 128.0, 122.0, 122.0, 125.0, 123.0, 131.0, 140.0,
> 137.0, 106.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 144.0, 145.0, 150.0, 149.0, 144.0, 136.0, 126.0, 128.0, 128.0, 118.0, 136.0, 129.0, 112.0, 44.0, 31.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 137.0, 145.0, 146.0, 145.0, 136.0, 133.0, 126.0, 125.0, 123.0, 113.0, 105.0, 128.0, 111.0, 5.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 124.0, 113.0, 115.0, 115.0, 121.0, 118.0, 120.0, 122.0, 118.0, 118.0, 83.0, 5.0, 0.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 113.0, 116.0, 117.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 97.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

the question is how to implement the data into the prediction model that has been made.

[my train model code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f-0hDtID4RXIgo9VPYt92O51zjxGweM-?usp=sharing)

```
public float interference(String s){
    float [] inputValue = new float[1];
    inputValue[0] = Float.valueOf(s);

    float[][] outputValue = new float[1][1];
    model.run(inputValue,outputValue);
    float inferedvalue = outputValue[0][0];

    return inferedvalue;
}

                    Date date = new Date();
                    ArrayList<String> dataa = new ArrayList<String>();
                    dataa.add(Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));

                    try {
                        model = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    float prediction = 1;
                    Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + prediction);

                    rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws  IOException{
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("model.tflite");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream((fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()));
    FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffSets = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLenght = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,startOffSets,declaredLenght);
}
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Tf lite text classification model gives you fair idea on how to predict the text. Read  this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification